# Database Query Help required in MySQL

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I am looking for help in writing a query of retrieving the values from 2 tables in [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

**The scenario is**

Table A

```
ID    Name    Marks
===================
23    John    67
45    Mark    45
12    Ram     87
```

Table B has the following Structure

```
ID    Name    Evaluation Marks
==============================
45    Mark    34
78    Chris   09
98    Nancy   10
23    John    12
```

I am trying to write a query, where if I execute the following query

```
Select "SOMETHING" from Table A where Id=45
```

I should get Marks Column as 45+34=79, which should fetch and sum from the both the Tables A and Table B.

If I execute the query with the Id=12.
Since the Id=12, does not exists in the Table B, I should get the Marks as 87.

What would a query for the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the id occurs only once in <strike>your tables</strike> table a, but could be missing in both. If it always exists in table `a`, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `UNION`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(marks), 0)
FROM
(
  SELECT marks FROM a WHERE id = 45
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(evaluation_marks) AS marks FROM b WHERE id = 45
) x
```

**Edit**

If you have all users in table a, then use

```
SELECT a.marks + COALESCE( SUM( b.evaluation_marks ), 0 )
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON ( b.id = a.id )
WHERE a.id = 45
GROUP BY a.id, a.marks
```

You should consider changing your table model though. Why do you store name and id twice? Can't you do it like that:

```
id    name    marks    evaluation marks
=======================================
12    Ram     87        0
23    John    67       12
45    Mark    45       34
78    Chris    0        9
98    Nancy    0       10
```

Comment: Your database change is valid, I will change the table structure, that will ease my development work, Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I have chose to store in a separate table is to allow multiple times Evaluation Marks can be stored for the particular id, the idea which you have given, if we use then I wont be able store the multiple times for a selected Id

Comment: @harigm: Then you should at least remove the name from the second table. See my updated answer (added SUM to second SELECT) to allow multiple evaluation marks. Please try it.

Comment: One Quick Clarification, Instead of Sum "COALESCE(SUM(marks), 0)", If I want to take the difference of the Select Query1 and Select Query2, Please suggest, 
As there is no DIFFERENCE or SUBTRACT Keyword in Mysql

Comment: @harigm: Use the second approach if possible and use `-` instead of `+`.

Comment: I just got that solution, thanks so much for your Suggestions